# In Xcode 5, can I share a same viewController.m file in two different storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a common viewController.m file that is meant to be shared between my different targets in Xcode 5. The idea is to have a common codebase with different skinnable UI, which means each target will have its own storyboard that reuse viewController.m file.

However, I have some some IBOutlets and IBActions in this .m file, could it be possible to link them to each different storyboard? I feel that it's unnecessary having to have a copy of viewController.m for each target.

Comment: I know this is nitpicking but it is "Xcode" ;) - I just couldn't resist, sry.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I've learned a proper way. Not an Objective-c developer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a universal app for iPhone and iPad, you will see, that the ViewControllers are shared in two different storyboards. So that shouldn't be a problem.